# $h=0.15, y(0.6)=?, y'=x(y+x)-2,y(0)=2$ , anwer correct upto 5 decimal places using Euler method

Tags: numerical-methods

use euler's method with step size $h=0.15$ to compute the approximate value of $y(0.6)$,correct upto five decimal places from initial value problem

$$y'=x(y+x)-2,\, \, y(0)= 2$$

Actually, I have found the answer for $y(0.6)$ with $h=0.15$ but i doesn't know wether the answer is correct upto 5 decimal places or not. How can i check the error and get the answer correct upto 5 decimal places?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they give you a method and a step size they shouldn't ask you to maintain a certain accuracy.  It would make more sense to ask you to choose the step size to get the accuracy desired.  You could [solve the differential equation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%3Dx(y%2Bx)-2) to get the exact answer and check yours against it, or you could use the derivatives of the solution in the error formula for the method to get a step size.